# TYPO3: Set type specific default values in TCA

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In my environment it is possible to set the default value for all content elements using

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['rowDescription']['config']['default'] = 'Default Value';
```

But overriding for one specific content element is not possible:

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['new_ce']['columnsOverrides']['rowDescription']['config']['default'] = 'New Description';
```

All other configurations can be changed (like the label):

```
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['new_ce']['columnsOverrides']['rowDescription']['label']= 'This is the new label';
```

How can I modify the default value for new_ce?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik not possible currently.

Technical reason in formEngine is that the TCA value defaults are applied before the 'type' is calculated since the default values influence type determination. Thus, they can't be swapped.

Also, this is not possible via page TSconfig since TCAdefaults also handles no type specific settings.

Comment: Do you know wether there is another (more difficult) solution like using a signal or something similar.

Comment: You might be able to reach your goal by adding a formEngine data provider in 'tcaDatabaseRecord' group after 'DatabaseRowInitializeNew'. This can't be done in a generic way, but you might be able to do parts of the type determination earlier for your use case in that provider and then set according defaults in data['databaseRow']. Code then depends on how flexible / least hard coded you want to solve that.

More details on this part of formEngine can be found at https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/FormEngine/DataCompiling/Index.html

Comment: Is this still not possible? Struggeling with this right now in 10.4 :P